# Two different page layout on a single object

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have two objects whose parent is another object. I want to set two different page layout on the parent just by differentiating the record type. How do i do it?

Comment: Are you implying that you want to decide the parent object's page layout based on the Record Type of one of its child objects?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to specify the page layout of an object based on the RecordType of that object per profile - this is done in the org setup.

[Assigning Record Types and Page Layouts in the Enhanced Profile User Interface](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm&language=en_US)

To specify record types and page layout assignments:

1. From Setup, click Manage Users | Profiles.
2. Select a profile.
3. In the Find Settings... box, enter the name of the object you want and
   select it from the list.
4. Click Edit.
5. In the Record Types and Page
   Layout Assignments section, make changes to the settings as needed.